# Close modal when clicking on overlay or close button?

Tags: jquery, window, modal-dialog

so I've read what I could find on doing this, but couldn't get it working.

This is the original code from the plugin:

```
// Close the modal window and overlay when we click the close button or on the overlay
$('.close-btn').click(function() {
    $('#overlay, .login-popup').fadeOut('300m', function() {
        $('#overlay').remove();
    });    
    return false;
});
```

I changed it to this:

```
$('.close-btn, #overlay').click(function() {
    $('#overlay, .login-popup').fadeOut('300m', function() {
        $('.close-btn').remove();
    });    
    return false;
});
```

Am I missing something here?
Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First check you have included any `latest version of jquery` in your file,

And write your code in [document.ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

Try this,

```
$(function(){// document.ready shorthand
    $('.close-btn').click(function() {
        $('#overlay,.login-popup').fadeOut('3000',function(){//use 3000 in place of 300m
            $('#overlay').remove();
        });    
        return false;
    });
});
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bGbu3/)

**Updated,** if your `elements` are `dynamic` then use [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on) like,

```
$(function(){// document.ready shorthand
    $(document).on('click','#overlay, .close-btn',function() {
        $('#overlay,.login-popup').fadeOut('3000',function(){//use 3000 in place of 300m
            $('#overlay').remove();
        });    
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: I did, but 2 things: 1. It seems like the overlay is still controlled by a button in your fiddle there. 2. If i misunderstood, I still tried it on my end, but it didn't work.

Comment: Can you make an `online demo`?

Comment: OneCraftyShop.com  this is my testing site at the moment so excuse the mess :) Click login in the nav menu and modal should pop up, but only the "x" (close) button workds. Clicking on the overlay doesn't do anything

Comment: Hopefully it is of some use to have it here so you can check it out, but I'm not sure that you can troubleshoot it??? I'm a newbie so forgive me. Thanks a lot by the way!